# Is it possible to debug python code running under an embedded interpreter without attaching it to its PID?

Tags: python, vscode-debugger, pdb

I'm debugging a script running in embedded interpreter hosted in an application from VS Code using PDB. Constantly launching the host and selecting its process ID from a dialog is a bit cumbersome. Sometimes its windows hide behind the IDE, which upsets my window placements in order to bring it to the foreground. The attaching process also makes it impossible to debug code in certain scenarios where the target script executes during the host's startup, which usually occurs well before I have a chance to attach to it.

Is there an alternative solution, such as a plugin or VSCode configuration? In C and C++, it's possible to insert a special function to break into the debugger. Does this exist for Python?

Answer (score 0):

There exists two options, the first, import pdb and use [pdb.set_trace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.set_trace):

```py
import pdb

pdb.set_trace()  # interpreter will break into pdb debugger here
```

The second is to use the builtin [breakpoint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint) function:

```py
breakpoint()  # breaks into debugger here
```

Comment: In both options, the application pauses during startup waiting for the debugger to attach. When VSCode successfully attaches to it, the application continues to pause and never breaks out to the debugger.

Comment: @ATL_DEV do you explicitly tell the application to continue (from within the debugger)? The command is `continue`

Comment: No luck. It just hangs there even when I enter continue from the debug. I also have another issue that I probably should open as a new question regarding importing built-in modules.